# save table after use mysql JOIN

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT prod_name,prod_desc,product_url,prod_price,img_name

FROM accu_product A, accu_product_imgs B

WHERE A.prod_id = B.prod_id
```

Is it possible to save the resulted table after use of join, and if yes, then what will the name of it. My query is as above.

Comment: There's this handy button called "CAPS LOCK" which lives on the left side of your keyboard. Learn to use it properly.

Answer (score 8):

```
CREATE TABLE whatever_you_want
SELECT
...
;
```

Comment: You are not answering the question: "save the resulted table..."

Comment: @alfasin - Am I not? The resulting table from the query is saved into a new table. 
You might to want to downvote ALL answers on this page, as Mchl talks about that my answer will **store** the result, and Poonam's answer is very close to mine.

Comment: sorry - my bad, I didn't understand your answer!

Comment: I tried, but I get this: "You last voted on this answer
18 hours ago
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited
(click on this box to dismiss)" - I'll upvote somewhere else to make it up for you. I apologize again.

Answer (score 1):

[Eugen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9312697/402253) will store the static result of your query. If you want a 'table' that updates as data in original tables change too, you can use views: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html

```
CREATE VIEW view_name
AS SELECT prod_name,prod_desc,product_url,prod_price,img_name
FROM accu_product A, accu_product_imgs B
WHERE A.prod_id = B.prod_id;
```

you can then query it as any other table

```
SELECT prod_name FROM view_name;
```

Comment: @user1210460: Loving others is really nice, but what about mark an answers or upvote the answers that helped you? :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE table_name

SELECT prod_name,prod_desc,product_url,prod_price,img_name

FROM accu_product A, accu_product_imgs B

WHERE A.prod_id = B.prod_id
```

try this: